# Access TreeView nodes inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, nodes

I have a `tree view`, which I'm populating using a server side method taking values from the DB.

The `tree view` gets populated and works fine.

I'm trying to access the `Tree View` nodes inside a `foreach` loop, but to my surprise, the count property shows value as 1.

PFB the codes:

```
public void PopulateTreeView()
        {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtUltimateParent = GetUltimateParent();
                DataTable dtA = GetParent();
                DataTable dtB = GetChildren();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
                dt1 = dtUltimateParent.Copy();
                dt2 = dtA.Copy();
                dt3 = dtB.Copy();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt3);
                ds.Relations.Add("FirstHierarchy", dt1.Columns["ultimateParentID"], dt2.Columns["ParentID"]);
                ds.Relations.Add("SecondHierarchy", dt2.Columns["ParentID"], dt3.Columns["ChildID"]);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                    foreach (DataRow ultimateRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        TreeNode ultimateNode = new TreeNode((string)ultimateRow["ultimateParentText"], Convert.ToString(ultimateRow["ultimateParentID"]));
                        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(ultimateNode);
                        ultimateNode.Expanded = true;
                        ultimateNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                        foreach (DataRow masterRow in ultimateRow.GetChildRows("FirstHierarchy"))
                        {
                            TreeNode masterNode = new TreeNode((string)masterRow["ParentText"], Convert.ToString(masterRow["ParentID"]));
                            ultimateNode.ChildNodes.Add(masterNode);
                            masterNode.Value = Convert.ToString(masterRow["ParentID"]);
                            masterNode.Expanded = false;
                            masterNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                            foreach (DataRow childRow in masterRow.GetChildRows("SecondHierarchy"))
                            {
                                TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode((string)childRow["ChildText"], Convert.ToString(childRow["ChildID"]));
                                masterNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
                                childNode.Value = Convert.ToString(childRow["Child"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now I am trying to access the Nodes using a `foreach` loop like below:

```
string[] myArray=an array having the texts of the Nodes
foreach(TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
{
    foreach(string s in myArray)
    {
     if(s==node.Text)
     {
      node.checked=true;
     }
   }
}
```

`TreeView1.Nodes` shows only one node which is `'All'`, also `TreeView1.Nodes.Count` comes as 1, but the whole tree view is populated and is pretty visible.

The Tree View is something like:

```
All
  A
    a1
    a2
  B
    b1
    b2
```

Am I doing the correct way to iterate amongst the tree view nodes?

Experts please guide over here.

Regards

Anurag

Comment: And how should I iterate over them?? Should I try to get the child nodes of 'All' and then iterate over them?

Comment: What do you want to iterate over them? (since you already have the object that you used to fill the treeview)
Check this link (The recursive function): http://forums.asp.net/t/1944560.aspx?get+a+list+of+treeview+selected+node+children

Comment: Thank you..let me try and see

Comment: @noobob I am able to iterate over the nodes, but the further stuff donot happen. I am trying to populate the tree view, and based upon some condition I'm trying to check few nodes. Code flow seems to be correct but the tree view doesn't populate after the node.checked=true happens.

Comment: Have you considered the page postback? (the tree control won't display your modifications only after a postback).
You need to provide more details how and where you are doing this implmentation or better google it

Comment: Yeah..I have considered postbacks and stuffs..May be I should post another question stating the pure facts and stuffs..Could you please wait for that question?? :)

Comment: @noobob I have posted another question having all details as to what I trying to do..Can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931971/strange-behavior-of-tree-view  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
All
  A
    a1
    a2
  B
    b1
    b2

TreeView1.Nodes //this shows the upper hierarchy...to access the nodes under All
```

you should use

```
TreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes  //this will show the nodes under All that means
```

A and B......so correct your code this way

```
TreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.......a1 and a2
```

Comment: I am able to iterate over the nodes now, but the further codes don't work or I'm perceiving in the wrong way.